# Library gets automatically included in contract

Tags: solidity, library

environment:

- all contracts use `pragma solidity ^0.4.17;`
- the compiler is `0.4.18+commit.9cf6e910.Emscripten.clang`
- OS is MacOS X

My token contract uses a Math library that is defined like so

```
library Math {...
```

In the token contract it is imported and then simply used in the functions

```
import "../Math.sol";
...
data.setBalances(src, Math.sub(data.balances(src), wad));
```

I compiled the contract with truffle compile and used the resulting bytecode to deploy the contract in `parity`

The surprising part is that it works and I'd like to understand why. There is no mention of the library in the bytecode. I would expect something like `____Math____` but this is not present.

Answer (score 2):

It appears that the latest version of solidity (or maybe prior to that) improved the usage of libraries and now `internal` functions will be copied into the calling contract to be able to use them with `JUMP` instead of `DELEGATECALL`

from the solidity [documentation on libraries](http://solidity.readthedocs.io/en/latest/contracts.html#libraries):

> Furthermore, internal functions of libraries are visible in all
>   contracts, just as if the library were a base contract. Of course,
>   calls to internal functions use the internal calling convention, which
>   means that all internal types can be passed and memory types will be
>   passed by reference and not copied. To realize this in the EVM, code
>   of internal library functions and all functions called from therein
>   will be pulled into the calling contract, and a regular `JUMP` call
>   will be used instead of a `DELEGATECALL`.